# How to delete two "underline-numeric" substrings from string using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, numeric, underline

I have a list of strings similar to `geo_drill_0_10m_therm_15_15` and I need to delete the last two "undeline-numeric" substrings (_15 and _15).

However in my list the numbers have different length of Digits (e.g. _1_14) and sometimes only one substring (e.g. _7) and sometimes none.

So far, I tried

`re.sub(r'(\d+\w?)(\d+)$', '', 'geo_drill_0_10m_therm_15_15')`
which as expected returns
`geo_drill_0_10m_therm_`

and

`re.sub(r'(\d+\w?)(\d+\w?)$', '', 'geo_drill_0_10m_therm_15_15')`
which I expected to do the job, however it returns the same

`geo_drill_0_10m_therm_`

Any ideas how to get rid of the last `"_"` with regex or even another solution without regex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `r'(_\d+\w?)(\d+)$'` ?

Comment: As far as I understand regex (i'm a beginner :), the first part `(_\d+\w?)` selects all numeric digits and only one alphabetic in this case "_" and in the second part `(\d+)` it selects only all numeric digits and of course starting from the end `$` of the string. But it's missing the last (or possible last) `_`.

Answer (score 1):

To remove any amount of `_` and 1+ digits at the end of the string you may use

```
re.sub(r'(?:_\d+)+$', '', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH6HLO/2)

To only remove 1 or 2 occurrences of `_<digits>` at the end, replace `+` with a limiting quantifier

```
r'(?:_\d+){1,2}$'
```

Adjust the min and max values as you see fit.